# Access kernel into a bundle extension class

Tags: php, symfony

I try to enhance one of my bundle Extension which load my YAML configuration files and I have to access the kernel class to use method `locateResource()`.

The goal is to load resources files without using :

```
__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'
```

Extension class looks like this :

```
class InnovaPathExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * Base path to the config directory of the bundle
     * @var unknown
     */
    const CONFIG_PATH = '@InnovaPathBundle/Resources/config/';

    /**
     * List of needed config files
     * @var array
     */
    protected $filesToLoad = array (
        // Services
        'services/services.yml',
        'services/listeners.yml',
        'services/managers.yml',
        'services/controllers.yml',

        // Parameters
        'parameters.yml',
    );

    /**
     * @see \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\ExtensionInterface::load()
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        foreach ($this->filesToLoad as $file) {
            // Check if resources exists
            try {
                $resource = static::CONFIG_PATH . $file;
                $filePath = $container->get('kernel')->locateResource($resource);
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unable to load "%s"', $resource), 0, $e);
            }

            // TODO : Load resource
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Instruction `$container->get('kernel')` throws an Exception 'The service definition "kernel" does not exist.'

If I check all services registered with `$container->getServiceIds()`, the only one I found is `service_container`.

Not a problem, I grab the service container and check services with `$container->get('service_container')->getServiceIds()`... And I only get one service : `service_container`.

I can't understand why... Is it DI-CEPTION ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended way is:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
        $container,
        new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
    );

    foreach ($this->filesToLoad as $file) {
        $loader->load($file);
    }
}
```

Other ways will not be recommended.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#loading-external-configuration-resources

Comment: Yes, it's what I did before starting enhancement. I will use `YamlFileLoader` and `FileLocator`, but I want to remove reference to `__DIR__` in constructor call.

Comment: Maybe, but if it's about SensioInsight notice, this is a fault positive. At this state the kernel is not loaded as you checked and use __DIR__ is not a bad coding solution but the expected solution. Check all major bundles from Sensio, KnpLabs, Liip, FOS, etc. This is the way to go!

Comment: OK. I didn't know `locateResource` method and I thought I could use it in my extension :(.